# Show column names in dataframe from Python MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, mysql-connector-python

I am importing data from a MySQL database into a Python project and the columns are printing as a series of a numbers instead of the actual column names.

This is my code so far for reference:

```
#Establish connection to database
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="xxxx",
  database="database"
)

#Use select statement on table
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM results LIMIT 5")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

#Convert to pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(myresult)
df
```

The output of which is the following table:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4252764 | 100595 | SP123 | 12543 |
| 4252765 | 100595 | SP124 | 12544 |
| 4252766 | 100595 | SP125 | 12545 |
| 4252767 | 100595 | SP126 | 12546 |
| 4252768 | 100595 | SP127 | 12547 |

However it is missing the column names and should look like this ideally:

| Id | StepId | name | ElementId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4252764 | 100595 | SP123 | 12543 |
| 4252765 | 100595 | SP124 | 12544 |
| 4252766 | 100595 | SP125 | 12545 |
| 4252767 | 100595 | SP126 | 12546 |
| 4252768 | 100595 | SP127 | 12547 |

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's a `pd.read_sql` command. Try `df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM results LIMIT 5", mydb)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes! That worked for me. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using cursor and then passing results as `DataFrame` using Pandas `read_sql` function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM results LIMIT 5"
 df_mysql = pd.read_sql(query, con = mydb)

 print(df_mysql)
```